# How to generate time delay when input frequency is high?

Tags: circuit-design, delay, gate-driving, time

Im trying to generate time delay for my gate drivers for a project im working on. But the issue is at lower frequencies my circuit works fine, as I ramp up the frequency (upto 250Khz) the output goes to zero.

I know the theory of generating time delay but have never worked with generating time delay in high frequency signals. My circuit is shown below, there **R(both) = 10kOhm**, and **C(both)=0.1uF**.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you feed the voltage of both capacitors to another waveform viewer. Then, you can see what happens at high frequencies.

Comment: First switch to using a gate with hysterisis (Schmitt trigger) like the 74HC14. This gate type will prevent multiple triggering on slow edge transitions, (even if the simulator seems to work).  Next, connect the second gate in your sequence string to the high side of the capacitor. You didn't mention how much delay you were looking for. When using higher frequencies and shorter delays decrease your R and C values. For finer delays (w/o even using extra RC parts) consider using a different number of gates in one of the strings.